# Getting "Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in." in aggregation pipeline, Why?

Tags: mongodb

I have tried to create view in mongoDb with aggregation pipeline when data cross it memory limit it's throwing **"Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in."** though i am using **allowDiskUse** Can anyone have any idea about it?

```
db.medicine_new.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$batchInfoList"
    },
],{ allowDiskUse: true })
```

Comment: How many record are present in batchInfoList ?

Comment: Are you sure that's the code generating the error?  `$unwind` is a very different stage than the `$group` mentioned in the error.